# Playing Vimeo videos on Windows 8 Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, vimeo

I am trying to play Vimeo videos from an app I am making for Windows 8 Phone.  A Vimeo app exists and I would preferably like to send it a video id and the Vimeo app plays it, but I cannot find anywhere explaining how to do that.

I have also tried to play it through the a webBrowserTask:

```
WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("http://vimeo.com/m/" + id, UriKind.Absolute);
webBrowserTask.Show();
```

but this also does not work, it just loads up the desktop version of Vimeo and a black screen where the video should be.  It seems as though Vimeo mobile does not work on Windows phones but I could have the wrong URL.

So I am a quite stuck and in need of guidance.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Cheers.

**UPDATE:** So it seems that the mobile version of the site does work on some windows phone devices.  I have tested it on a couple of Lumia 920 and it works but does not seem to work on the Lumia 520.  I have checked the supported video codecs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462087(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_VideoSupport) and both the 520 and 920 support the same videos.  So it could be a bug at Vimeo.  What do you guys think?